# Using Set-AzStorageBlobContent to upload only new content without prompts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm enumerating a local folder and uploading to Azure storage.  I want to only upload *new* content to my Azure storage.  If I use Set-AzStorageBlobContent with -Force, it'll overwrite everything.  If I use it without -Force, it'll prompt on items that already exist.  I can use Get-AzStorageBlob to check if the item already exists, but it prints red errors if the item does *not* exist.  I can't find a combination of these items that gracefully uploads only new content without printing any errors or prompting.  Am I using the wrong approach?

FINAL EDIT: adding working solution based on suggestions from Ivan Yang.  Now only new files are uploaded, without any error messages.  The key was to use -ErrorAction Stop to convert the error message into an exception, and then catch the exception.

```
# In my code this is part of a Test-Blob function that returns $blobFound
$blobFound = $false
try
{
    $blobInfo = Get-AzStorageBlob `
        -Container $containerName `
        -Context $storageContext `
        -Blob $blobPath `
        -ErrorAction Stop

    $blobFound = ($null -ne $blobInfo)
}
catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException]
{
    # Eat the error that'd otherwise be printed
}

# Note in my code this is actually a call to my Test-Blob function
if ($false -eq $blobFound)
{
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent `
        -Container $containerName `
        -Context $storageContext `
        -File $sourcePath `
        -Blob $blobPath `
        -Force  # -Force is unnecessary but just being paranoid to avoid prompts
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have mentioned trying `Get-AzStorageBlob`, why not use it continually?

The trick here is that you can use `try-catch-finally`, which can properly handle the error if the blob does not exist in azure.

The sample code works at my side for uploading a single file, and you can modify it to upload multi-files:

```
$account_name ="xxx"
$account_key ="xxx"      
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -StorageAccountKey $account_key    

#use this flag to determine if a blob exists or not in azure. And assume it exists at first.
$is_exist = $true
try
{
 Get-AzStorageBlob -Container test3 -Blob a.txt -Context $context -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException]
{
 #if the blob does not exist in azure, do the following
 $is_exist = $false
 Write-Output "the blob DOES NOT exists."
}
finally
{
 #only execute the code when the blob does not exist in azure blob storage.
 if(!$is_exist)
 {
 Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container test3 -File "d:\myfolder\a.txt" -Blob a.txt -Context $context
 Write-Output "uploaded!"
 }

}
```

Comment: I just tried that, but the error is still printed by Get-AzStorageBlob.  It doesn't seem to be an exception that's thrown out of the call, just printed in output.

Comment: @SueLoh, please add "-ErrorAction Stop" at the end of "Get-AzStorageBlob". I have edited your code in your post by adding "-ErrorAction Stop". Please take a try, I tested your code with the change, works good:)

Comment: I just got to test it and it does work.  I'll update my comments and mark this as answered.  Thank you for helping me sort this out!

Answer (score 1):

Not a PowerShell solution but I would suggest that you take a look at [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). It's like RoboCopy but for Azure storage. A command line tool which allows you to synch, copy, move and more. It's free, works on macOS, Linux and Windows. And also, it is *fast*!

I use AzCopy from PowerShell scripts and it makes lie a lot easier (I'm managing millions of files and the stability and speed of AzCopy really helps)

Answer (score 0):

This command is not smart enough to detect which files are new. You need to keep in the folder just the files you want to upload.

Comment: Bummer, but thanks for the confirmation.  I'll have to build something to detect new content on the source side.

Comment: take a look on Azure Data Factory. It has a "Copy Data" which is smart enough to get only new ones.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Force all the time.

The alternative is to check for existing file, download the file content, compare the files, and upload if different. The amount of processing/IO will only increase this way.

Comment: Not really - my files are large.  It's quicker to check for their existence than to re-upload.  But I can see that with small files this is the right trade-off.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, it depends what you mean with “new” content. If files are write-once (no updates), then yes you are right. But if file content can change, then my answer is the most efficient (unless there is a possibility to compare hashes).